# ngModel in Angular Form

Tags: html, angular, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to access to data form my form in the TS file.
I got error : RROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

My code is like this:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { employee } from '../models/Employee';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms'; 
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-form',
  templateUrl: './employee-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-form.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeFormComponent implements OnInit {\

  data: employee;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit(form:NgForm ) { 
    alert("Hello "  + JSON.stringify(this.data));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
    <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="form">name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"  [(ngModel)]="data.name" required>
      </div>

      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I didnt find my mistake, any idea?

thanks

Comment: What does "data" contain?

Comment: in the begining is empty. I want to pass the input to the "data"

Comment: Please check the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Do the template binding with a safe navigation operator. This way, if "data" is not defined, your code will not try to read prop `name` from it.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"  [(ngModel)]="data?.name" required>
```

In case, if the prop `data` is undefined and you want to use `data` as a container to store the form values then you have to at least create an empty object, for example, initialize data as `data = {}` It will create keys on the fly.

Comment: hi, data is "employee" type. on "employee" there is "name"

Comment: The issue is one of timing. Your form may try to display `data` (or `employee`) before the data is obtained from a data source. So the code generates a `can't read property` error. Then, we it does get the data, your form will update. Just try the above suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that you shouldn't make the data null ever.
And initialize the data as

```
 data = {} as employee;
```